# How to read a protected .bas file which has "line buffer overflow"?

Tags: file, protected, gw-basic

I have an old file which I'd like to read its code.

The file has no extension. Right click + open with notepad gives me something like that :

> 1         N¦öêS‚        `šØ¢¾Œ2               €               € 3 
>   ôI¿Õ^J‚        á

So I've renamed and put an extension to this file ".BAS"

I've tried to open it with PC-BASIC.

I've opened PC-BASIC + written " LOAD"NFTRANS.BAS" + Enter (NFTRANS was the original name of my file)

And then I get the following error :

> Line buffer overflow

The idea was to open it and then save it this way :

> SAVE"NFTRANS", A

to get rid of the protection and be able to read the code with Notepad.

So my problem is that I'm facing a Line Buffer Overflow error which doesn't allow me to save my file !

How to deal with the problem ?!

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: You need to figure/find out which file format the file has first. You say you have an old file which you'd like to "read its code". How do you know it is code? What is the purpose of the original file? How do you use it?

Comment: Hi Lasse, I have a lot of *.bas files that i unprotected and read their code with Notepad using the method below. This file has no extension. However, in one of the other .bas file, I've read the command "750 OPEN "r",#2,"NFTRANS",34". That's why I've supposed its original format was also .bas

Comment: That just seems to open the file for reading, you sure it contains code at all? Perhaps it's just a data file for the program that contained that line 750. I say "open for **reading**" because of that `"r"`, it's been ... a while ... since I used gw-basic. From [some random documentation I found using Google](http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/open.html) it seems that statement opens the file for reading with a record length of 34. Doesn't sound to me like this is code.

Comment: I don't know.. maybe you're right.. The file is 174ko. I should check if its weight is always the same or not. I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: If it is a data-file for the program with that 750 line, you should probably just leave it as-is, if you've "unprotected" the code in the sense that you convert it from some internal format to text-format, that file probably doesn't need to change at all.

Comment: Hmm .. ok thank you for your answer. How do you understand the "34"? What do you mean with "Record length of 34" ?

Anyway, so the current program seems to use the NFTRANS file to save data. But that means that another program uses this NFTRANS file to read its data.. I'll try to find it then ! Thank you once more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192184/discussion-between-manny-and-lasse-vagsaether-karlsen).